# Trigger a Button inside WebView

Tags: swift, xcode, webview, webkit

I have a HTML Page with different Buttons inside there which I opening with a WebView. 
Now I will click on a button inside the WebView and will have an app action.

Is there a function in WebKit that gives a responds to such taps?

Answer (score 0):

**Using this delegate method you will track button action in the app.**

```
  let htmlString = "<a class=\"buton\" href=\"http://someaction\">Click</a>"                

  webView.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)
  webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

**WKNavigationDelegate**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated {
            if let url = navigationAction.request.url {
                if url.absoluteString == "http://someaction/" {
                    print("Action trigure")
                } else {
                    print("No action trigure")
                }
            }
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
```